# Nonlinear state space representation involving derivatives

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory

For the follwing nonlinear system:
$$\dot x_{1} = 2/b \cdot [(c_{1}-u_{1}) \dot u_{1} + (r_{1}-u_{2})
 \dot u_{2}]x_{1} \\
    \dot x_{2} = 2/b \cdot 
    [(c_{2}-u_{1}) \dot u_{1} + (r_{2}-u_{2}) \dot u_{2}]x_{2} \\
    \dot x_{3} = 2/b \cdot 
    [(c_{1}-u_{3}) \dot u_{3} + (r_{1}-u_{4}) \dot u_{4}]x_{3} \\
    \dot x_{4} = 2/b \cdot 
    [(c_{2}-u_{3}) \dot u_{3} + (r_{2}-u_{4}) \dot u_{4}]x_{4} \\
    \\ \\
    y_{1} = x_{1} + x_{2} \\
    y_{2} = x_{3} + x_{4}
$$ 
I am looking for a state space representation in the form:

$$
\mathbf{\dot x} = A(\mathbf{x})\mathbf{x} + B(\mathbf{x})\mathbf{u} \\
y = C\mathbf{x}$$
Is it possible to transform the system in a way that this is possible?

Comment: I am not sure but for a constant input $u$ you have $\dot{u} = 0$ and $\dot{x} = 0$, a loss of controllability. This seems to be problematic.

Answer (score 0):

All time derivatives are linearly dependent on $\dot{u}_1$ through $\dot{u}_4$, so if one defines the input vector as

$$
\mathbf{u} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{u}_1 \\ \dot{u}_2 \\ \dot{u}_3 \\ \dot{u}_4
\end{bmatrix},
$$

one also has to include $u_1$ through $u_4$ as states of the system. This would also imply that $A(\mathbf{x})=0$. The required $B(\mathbf{x})$ should then follow relatively straightforward, i.e. the Jacobian of $\mathbf{x}$ with respect to $\mathbf{u}$.

Comment: Note also that there are products $u_1\dot{u}_1$, $u_2 \dot{u}_2$, and thus you have to include the signals $u_1$, $u_2$ in the extended state vector.

Comment: @Arastas that is also what I meant with "one also has to include $u_1$ through $u_4$ as states of the system".